# To code a sum of functions in$\:\mathbf R$ .

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like some general tips on how to code sequences of functions of the following type in$\:\mathbf R$ :

$$\text F_n\equiv\sum_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}f_n$$

For instance, let's say $$f_n:x\in\mathbb {R\backslash2\pi Z}\mapsto \sin(nx)$$

I know how to plot that sequence of functions but not the partial sum (see below).

```
> x <- seq(0,pi,length=1e4)
> M <- matrix(data=NA, nrow = 1e4, ncol = 4)
> f <- function (n,x) sin(n*x)
> for (i in 1:4) {M[,i] <- f(n[i],x)}
> n <- c(1,2,3,10)
 matplot(x,M,type="l",ylab="fn(x)")
```

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: matlab ? if so there's a tag for it.

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer, but [SO actually has an "R" tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), so it may be better to ask questions like "how do I program this?" there.  It seems off-topic for both the real-analysis and sequences-and-series tags (and since we don't seem to have an R tag here, I don't know how I'd re-tag it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
K = apply(M, 1, cumsum)
matplot(x,t(K), type="l",ylab="Fn(x)")
```

[image]

Comment: Bull's eye mate